# How to remove Left recursive in this ANTLR grammar?

Tags: parsing, programming-languages, antlr, grammar

I am trying to parse CSP(Communicating Sequential Processes) [CSP Reference Manual](http://www.comlab.ox.ac.uk/ucs/cspm.pdf). I have defined following grammar rules.

```
assignment
    : IDENT '=' processExpression
    ;
processExpression
    :   ( STOP
        | SKIP
        | chaos
        | prefix
        | prefixWithValue
        | seqComposition
        | interleaving
        | externalChoice

        ....

seqComposition
    :   processExpression ';' processExpression
    ;
interleaving
    :   processExpression '|||' processExpression
    ;
externalChoice
    :   processExpression '[]' processExpression
        ;
```

Now ANTLR reports that

```
seqComposition 
interleaving
externalChoice
```

are left recursive . Is there any way to remove this or I should better used Bison Flex for this type of grammar. (There are many such rules)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define a `processTerm`.  Then write rules looking like

```
assignment
    : IDENT '=' processExpression
    ;
processTerm
    :   ( STOP
        | SKIP
        | chaos
        | prefix
        ...
processExpression
    :   ( processTerm
        | processTerm ';' processExpression
        | processTerm '|||' processExpression
        | processTerm '[]' processExpression

        ....
```

If you want to have things like `seqComposition` still defined, I think that would be OK as well.  But you need to make sure that the parsing of `processExpansion` is going to always consume more text as you proceed through your rules.

Comment: Deleted my answer. Separating terms from operators is definitely the way to go! It would probably be best to factor out processTerm to avoid backtracking, though, unless ANTLR does that automatically?

Comment: `processExpression : processTerm ( ';' processExpression | '|||' processExpression | '[]' processExpression | ) ;`

Comment: @ikegami: ANTLR is supposed to compile a DFA to do lookahead, which should factor that out automatically.  Though it can't hurt to do that for it.  Unless, of course, you forget to make a `processTerm` a `processExpansion`. :-P

Comment: @btilly, I didn't forget, if you're implying that I did. Note the empty alternation.

Comment: @ikegami: Clearly I hadn't noted it before.  In part, possibly because that possibility was first on my list and last on yours.

Comment: @btilly, That was intentional. If productions are attempted in order of appearance, placing the empty production last can reduce backtracking.

Comment: Thanks for answer but problem is that Term is actually expression in this case. a seqComposition can be seqComposition ';' seqComposition. How should I model that?

Comment: @tasawer-khan: Can a `seqComposition` be empty?  If not then if you look far enough to the left, a `seqComposition` is always something simpler followed by `;` followed by something more complex.  Give that something simpler a name.  If it can be empty, break out that as a special case, and now a `seqComposition` has to either start with a `;` or some kind of simpler term and you no longer have recursion.

Comment: @ikegami: Ah.  ANTLR compiles a DFA to match forward whatever it can without backtracking, so normally you should do very little backtracking.

Comment: @btilly thank you for your answer. I am learning techniques like you told. But after this answer I am sure this can be done so it is worth spending time. It is my first parser so will take some time to everything right. Thank you for providing very useful info and motivation.

Comment: Currently ANTLR does not perform automatic left-factoring. Depending on the maximum number of terminals matched by the `processTerm` rule, left factoring the `processTerm` in `processExpression` could lead to substantially reduced memory overhead and overall parser performance.

Answer (score 1):

Read the guide to [removing left recursion in on the ANTLR wiki](https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Left-Recursion+Removal).  It helped me a lot.